# `Parameters` utility type returns `never` for readonly array arg

Tags: typescript

I am seeing a weird (*maybe* ‍♂️) behavior of `Parameters` utility type. Given code:

```
const testFn = (...args: readonly number[]) => args;
type l = typeof testFn;
type e = Parameters<l>;
```

It doesn't change if I use `ReadonlyArray<number>` instead, though that is to be expected since they are synonyms.

Why does TypeScript say that type of `e` is `never`? This was tested on TypeScript v4.3.5.
[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiYYF4YAoB0uCGATgOYQBcMASvHgCbgA2AngIIEF6MA8YArgLYAjeAQB8ASnQiYhEgG4AUFEYAHeDHro4K+CABmcRFBQKlqmGowAFQnj7wEBCJ3oiFQA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue: [Inference from rest parameters has strange inconsistent results #37193](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37193).